# angular 4 simply set a radiobutton in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, radio-button, checked

This has to be simple, but I don't want to use jQuery.
I need to set a specific radio button control.  I have its Id, so I tried:

```
let radiobutton = document.getElementById("Standard");
radiobutton.checked = true;
```

I found examples on the web just like the above,
but Typescript/Javascript gives me the error message:
"Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'"

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not to use Angular binding?

Comment: That is not right way to do things in Angular2. But look for https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Comment: I could use some help in how to "do it right" in Angular.  I don't understand binding though I keep reading about it, it hasn't sunk in.  Can you say more?

Comment: I tried using setattribute like:
document.getElementsByTagName("cs-input-radio")[0].setAttribute("checked", "true");  but it didn't work... am I setting the wrong attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing document.getElementById, use @ViewChild and template variables.
Here is an example:

HTML:

```
<input #checkbox1 type="checkbox" [checked]="true" (change)="onChange(1, checkbox1)"/>{{name1}}
<br>
<input #checkbox2 type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(2, checkbox2)"/>{{name2}}
```

**Typescript:**

```
  name1 = 'Angular 2';
  name2 = 'Angular 4';

  @ViewChild("input1") input1;
  @ViewChild("input2") input2;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.input1.checked = true;
    console.log("Checkbox1 is checked -  ", this.input1.checked);
    console.log("Checkbox2 is checked -  ", this.input2.checked);

  }

  onChange(checkbox, item){
    console.log("Checkbox%d was checked", checkbox);
    console.log("Checkbox%d is checked -  ",checkbox, item.checked);

  }
```

**[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pqrukn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**